# Apache PDFBOX renderImageWithDPI UTF-8 Issue

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to export PDF pages to PNG using Apache PDFBOX(2.0.8) PDFRenderer - renderImageWithDPI . Everything works fine except when we have UTF-8 characters in text png show boxes instead of chracter . If i get text content I can see correct characters but image rendering is having this issue

Comment: **a** please update to the current PDFBox 2 version. Currently that's 2.0.19. **b** UTF-8 is not a regular PDF encoding. Thus, I assume that either your description is wrong and you simply want to express problems with characters which are not in the ASCII or probably Latin-1 character set, or you indeed handled a pdf as UTF-8 encoded text and so most likely damaged it. **c** to help you we need to be able to reproduce the issue. Thus, please share the pdf in question and your pivotal code.

Comment: Yes I am using 2.0.19 I found issue but still don't have solution. It is not an utf-8 character issue  but in pdf glyph symbol is used and pdfbox give warning  

org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.Type1Glyph2D getPathForCharacterCode
WARNING: No glyph for 115 (sigma) in font Symbol

Comment: Strange thing is that if we have embedded font which doesn’t contain the required glyphs, how pdf viewer is able to show the same symbol

Comment: Tilman if you want to see pdf 
https://1drv.ms/b/s!AtnBIgbwp9wZh-J7kNuu1ZY0JizgVg?e=DgzKj5                                                 On page 18 you will see symbol σ

Comment: I see the σ symbol. Do you have the "Symbol" font installed on your machine? You need it.

Comment: Thanks alot Tilman. I install couple of fonts installed which I think have greek symbols. But somehow not working. I installed one more tahomabd.ttf. It worked now..

Comment: I think other tools which earlier working embedding there own fonts.

Comment: The best would be a font named symbol.ttf. If you have it, but it doesn't contain the "σ", then try to find a newer one.